# problem with painting weights

Tags: modeling, bones, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

I was recently practicing bone animation with the IK and FK systems, the problem is that when I perform the union by automatic weights there is a blind union spot that I cannot find and that deforms my character's legs, I tried deactivating the deform box of my controllers, bones and mechanisms but there is still the same error, even when I enter the weight painting and look for the origin, I can't find it anywhere.
[image]

Occurs with any movement of the leg regardless of which bone is selected.

I already have this problem for several months and I redid my skeleton several times, even then I can't solve it.
many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When Rigging Characters make sure to name the weight map the same name as the bone this is how blender recognizes and link weight maps to the bones.

Draw weight maps manually sometimes automatic is not accurate.